# Process of handing over source code to a customer

Tags: source-code, customer-relations

Should I just copy the project files to him? Should I sit and explain the code to him ? If so, up to which level of details? Or do I just tell him where everything is within the solution and not how the code works?

I would appreciate your input

Comment: Please fix the title. "A code" is usually a single number, as it is used in encryption, or to unlock a feature of an application. "Code" is written software.

Comment: For any software project you have, you should be using **source code control**, i.e. Git, Bitbucket, etc. giving code to a client at that point becomes s matter of giving them ownership of the repository. If they ask you to tell them how the code works, make sure that the agreement to do so was specified in your contract. Otherwise, the client should be hiring developers that can understand your code.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks for your suggestion, you're right, I thought Source-code will be more expressive.

Comment: It's not "a source-code". It's "source code". No "a". No hyphen.

Comment: It really depends on what the customer wants.  If they know about software development, they will probably want some basic build documentation along with working code.  If they don't know anything about software development you'll need to decide for yourself what is a reasonable (and ethical) handover.  Either way, that should all be specified ahead of time in your contract with the customer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is something that should be specified in the contract between the developer and the customer. There is no one standard way of doing this, and whether any explanation is needed depends entirely on the client, the nature of the code, and many other details of the situation.

Comment: @gnasher729:  English may not be the OP's first language.  Nitpicking what he wrote is bad form, especially when you have enough rep to edit the question.

Comment: I'm quite sure English is not the OP's first language. Consider that he might have learned something. Not telling him about mistakes that really destroy the meaning of his title is bad form.

Comment: @gnasher729:  This is probably not the place for an extended discussion, but the question disambiguates the title and the OP would have seen the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a copy of the code.

You take that copy of the code to a different computer and verify that you can build the application on that computer from the code.

If that doesn't work, then you fix all the problems in the code until it works to build the application on your computer, and on the second computer.

You document all the steps that are needed to build the application, so that another person can build the application using those instructions only. When you document the steps, you assume that the reader can read the instructions, but not your mind.

You give the code and the instructions to a secretary at your company, or to your mother, and make sure that they can build the application following the instructions without asking you any questions.

Until that works, you improve the instructions.

At that point, you hand over the code and the instructions to the customer.

Comment: Or you don't do any of that if you haven't been paid to do it.  What you're describing is the courteous thing to do but not necessarily the OP's obligation.  It really all boils down to the original agreement between company and customer.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't work on any machine other than the original developer's machine, which happens often enough, that's not working code.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this the same as when handing over to any other maintainer:

- Include the source control files so that they have the entire history of the project.
- Make sure that the code builds from source with just one command. Nothing is more depressing then having to spend several hours/days before getting it to compile.
- If external resources are required (say a database) the code for setting them up should be part of the source control. (Think: Migrations and/or for example a Vagrant file for local testing.)
- Documentation:

  - A High Level overview of the project (the different layers, their intent and their dependencies)
  - Deployment configuration: How to deploy (again, ideally with one command), where to find the log files, which firewalls, reverse proxies, ... are passed, credentials for databases etc.
  - Anything that you think your client could benefit from...  (ex: ubiquitous language, design/architectural decisions etc)
  - Most importantly, **keep documentation as short as possible**. If you hand over 50+ pages of documentation, chances are it will never be read. (it all depends on the size of the project of course but less is almost always better)

Going through the code with the client: I guess this is up to him. If the client will continue work on it right away, going through the code together is a very good idea. He will not remember everything you say and show but will have some general idea of your project layout.